# While loop wont repeat itself

Tags: java, while-loop

I need to let the user input an operand, input 2 integers, display the result, and repeat. It wont repeat and when you input an integer to continue, it terminates. Any help would be appreciated, Ive been stuck for a while now! Thanks.

```
package lab03;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * 
 */
public class Lab03 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n, p, q = 1;
    boolean run = true;
    String operator;

    while (run == true) {

        operator = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter one of + - * / ");
        String trimOperator = operator.trim();
        char m = trimOperator.charAt(0);

        String firstOperand = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Enter first integer operand: ");
        n = Integer.parseInt(firstOperand);

        String secondOperand = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Enter second integer operand: ");
        p = Integer.parseInt(secondOperand);

        switch (m) {
        case '+':
            System.out.println(n + " plus " + p + " is " + (n + p));
            run = false;
            break;
        case '-':
            System.out.println(n + " minus " + p + " is " + (n - p));
            run = false;
            break;
        case '*':
            System.out
                    .println(n + " multiplied by " + p + " is " + (n * p));
            run = false;
            break;
        case '/':
            System.out.println(n + " divided by " + p + " is " + (n / p)
                    + " with remainder " + (n % p));
            run = false;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid character");
            run = false;
            break;

        }

        String lastInteger = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Enter 0 to quit, or any other integer to continue. ");
        q = Integer.parseInt(lastInteger);
        System.out.println(q);
        System.exit(0);

        continue;
    }
}
```

Sorry for lack of comments.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to understand why it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: You have `System.exit(0);` at the end of your while loop...

Comment: @DennisMeng Is right. Also, you have a `continue;` as the last statement in your loop body, which is (1) inaccessible in this context and (2) pointless even if accessible since the loop would `continue` by default and re-evaluate.

Comment: Not only that, but you set run = false in every case of the switch statement, so there's no way for it to be true at the bottom of the while clause (even if you did get past the System.exit somehow).

Comment: Thank you all!! All your advice helped greatly, it works perfectly now!

Comment: you can use println statement to track run variable..